# What type of fill to use to raise grade in back yard

Tags: drainage, landscaping

There is a small section of my back yard that is adjacent to my house and slopes towards it. The yard itself is predominately graded away from the house, so I just need to raise the grade in this section to ensure that water does not run towards my house when it rains.

I plan to cover the area with peastone as finish(currently just dirt), but what type of fill should I use under the peastone to actually raise the grade. Should I use clay, or something else that doesn't drain, or is topsoil sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

Topsoil is sufficient. After all, that's what is under it. ;) And I would suggest using bull rock instead of peastone; I've found that the peastone is difficult to a) walk on, b) keep clear of leaves and other debris.